# MathJax v2.7.2 beta

Tags: discussion, mathjax

**Update:** [v2.7.2 has been released](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-7-2-now-available/), so we're switching over to the non-beta version today.

---

MathJax v2.7.2 has entered the public beta phase. We're setting it up here to kick the tires and help out with testing.

This release includes a workaround for a regression in Safari as well as over 30 other bug fixes. The full list of changes is available [on mathjax.org](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-7-2-beta-now-available/#new-in-release).

As always, we will be monitoring this post for any bug reports or missing features.

Comment: Just a minor note some larger posts of mine tend to take a long time to render the mathjax. Could an added feature at some point be that only the portions in screen be rendered? Or maybe do a general efficiency update? It's probable that mathjax wasn't built for throughput.

Comment: @Typhon Well, I mostly meant "missing features" as related to the beta test... I don't know enough about the MathJax library to be able to tell off-hand if partial page rendering is something we could implement on our (as in Math.SE) end or if it's something that needs to go into the library itself. Folks from MathJax *are* also looking at this thread, though, so perhaps one of them can weigh in.

Comment: Ok. Don't forget as well though that the library needs an efficiency update as well. It renders quite slow for me.

Comment: @typon do you have an example of a post that's slow for you? FWIW, there have been discussions about performance on meta in the past. We at MathJax continue to work on improvements and have discussed alternative approaches (e.g., server-side rendering) with the team at Stack Overflow. If you see unusually bad performance, e.g., compared to equivalent content on another site, in particular one not using the 2.7.2 beta, then please post examples. If not, then this is probably off-topic for this thread.

Comment: @Adam There's a [request over on Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/update-to-mathjax-2-7-2-please) to enable this there as well. Is there a defined timeline for when this gets enabled network-wide? Are you just waiting for 2.7.2 to get out of beta?

Comment: @E.P. We're switching network-wide today.